# Reading all files in a directory

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, scope, filesystems

here is the code snippet of what I am working with right now...

```
/* 
    Module: inputReader.js, directoryScanner.js (included)
    Description: Basic file reader returns string of contents of a file from a set file name
    Needs to be done: Add key listener to allow for a dynamic file name
 */

// Declare node.js module dependencies from API
var fs = require('fs'), 
    wrench = require('wrench'),
    util = require('util')

// Define module to be exported as a function(s)
module.exports = {
    dirRead: function() {
        var rootfolder = './node_modules';
        var filteredfiles = [];
        var files = [];
        var fileextension = '.html';

        files = wrench.readdirSyncRecursive(rootfolder)
        for (var i = 0; i<files.length; i++) { 
            if (files[i].indexOf(fileextension) != -1) { 
                filteredfiles.push(files[i]);
            }
        }
        return filteredfiles;
    },

    fileRead: function() {
        // Call synchronous fileSystem function readFileSync on file name
        for(i = 0; i<filteredfiles.length; i++) {
            var temp = fs.readFileSync(filteredfiles[i].toString(), 'utf8')
            return temp
        }
    }
};
```

I am exporting a module of 2 different functions; the first (readDir) that reads a directory and its' subdirectories for a list of files and the second (readFile) which relies on the first (reads the list of files from the first function and actually goes through each file).

The problem is when I try to call that look of filteredfiles in the 2nd function, readFile, I get an error saying filteredfiles is undefined.

I am not sure how to fix this, may someone help me please? (My guess is a scope problem)...

```
res.send(reader.dirRead()) and then, res.send(reader.fileRead(reader.dirRead()))
```

Comment: Have you tried making sure the var is global?

Comment: I made the variables global and it has worked to a degree; the readFile function is reading in the paths, but it is reading in the entire path. c:\User\Brian\documents\visualizer\express\etc..
Is there a way for me to format that string within the array because the throwing in the full path as an input for the readFile method does not work; (Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory)

Comment: Where is the directory in relation to the JS file.  You can use simple references such as "../" for the next higher directory.

Answer (score 0):

filteredfiles is declared locally in dirRead function (so it is not visible for fileRead function). You must declare it in some higher scope, or pass it as a fileRead parameter.